# Evaluate the double integrals given

Tags: calculus, integration

$\:\int \:\int _R\:\:$  (x+y) dA where R is the region bounded by $y=0$,$y=x^2$ and $x=1/3$. Can anyone help me how to solve the integral. I sketch the graph but I am confuse which region should I chooese.And is it possible to solve it without sketching a graph? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region $R$ is the area under the curve $y=x^2$, above the line $y=0$ and between $x=0$ and $x=\frac13$. Symbolically, you can solve this integral by writing $dA$ as $dxdy$ and parametrizing $R$ in terms of $x,y$.

$\int_R (x+y) dA = \int_0^{\frac13} \int_0^{x^2} (x+y) dy\: dx$
$ = \int_0^{\frac13}[xy + \frac{y^2}2]\Big|_0^{x^2}dx = \int_0^{\frac13}x^3 + \frac{x^4}2 - 0 \: dx = [\frac{x^4}4 + \frac{x^5}{10}]\Big|_0^{\frac13} = \frac1{324} + \frac1{2430} = \frac{17}{4860}$

Comment: omg thank you so much. I am a little bit confuse about this question but gladly you help me. THANKS!